# Connected Strings Pattern in C

Tags: c, arrays, nested-loops

I want to implement connected strings pattern. Below as you see the places which are filled with
non-zeros that is 1 are connected and making a pattern like "U" and thus its position are also printed in "U" connected shape.
Also there are two 1's connected at last column .
Like this i want all places which are filled by non-zero elements and if are connected , want sequence in connected pattern.
I have a tried a code but stuck at some point.
Please provide a optimal solution.
thanks.

```
    void main()
    {
    int a[10][10],i,j;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            if(a[i][j]>0&&a[i+1][j]>0)
            {
                printf("%d (%d,%d)",a[i][j],i,j);
            }
        }
     }

Expected output
0   0   0   0   0
1   0   1   0   0
1   0   1   0   1
1   1   1   0   1
0   0   0   0   0

connected strings are: 1(1,0) , 1(2,0), 1( 3,0) 1(3,1) ,1(3,2),1(2,2),2(1,2)
connected strings are: 1(2,5) , 1(3,5)
```

Comment: `stuck at some point` Where?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If its a T How do you wish to get it printed? One way is to try recursion to print every set node around a set node. printSetNode(..){if(a[i][j]>0){print a[i][j]. Call right, left, up,  down}

Comment: this code is only giving the no of 1's present. I want them in proper pattern.

Comment: Your code is no where close yo your output. Your array is not initialized and you are priniting your array which will lead to undefined behavior

Comment: @thepace please elaborate.

Comment: @Gopi plese suppose it as it is intialize, focus in output.

Comment: Will add my code. Before that could you please clarify if you wish to correct the current algorithm or have any algorithm that works.

Comment: change your if to `if(a[i][j]>0 && (a[i+1][j]>0  || a[i][j+1]>0))`

Comment: i don't have any other algorithm, please proceed.

Comment: @Himanshu it can be same, i want output in expected pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Breadth-First-Search** or **Depth-First-Search.**

Comment: @YagyaMaharshi I can just assist you. I have given you the algorithm itself. Try google it. You will get many.

Comment: welcome :) It is not necessary to tell thanks and all. We are here with our own interest.

Answer (score 0):

*what I am using*

To hold patterns I am using a dynamic array(pointers to pointers),`referenceToPatterns[]`, to store position of elements. I am initiating new dynamic array, if I know that it does not fit into existing patterns.

*Algorithm*

-- Traverse through elements and if you find `1`, and confirming that you have a existing pattern that it can fit into then place the position in that pattern, else I initiate a new dynamic array hoping that this will be the root of the new pattern.

-- Since you are traversing individual elements, there is a change that certain element will go into multiple patterns, existing.

-- merge the patterns, which share a common ordered pair.

this what I get by running the below code.

`referenceToPattern[0] = { {1,0} ,{2,0} ,{3,0}, {3,1}, {3,2}};`

`referenceToPattern[1] = { {1,2}, {2,2} , {3,2}};`

`referenceToPattern[2] = {{2,4},{3,4}};`

since the patterns 0 ,1 share {3,2}, they make a single pattern.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
int insertIntoPattern(int* element, int* referenceToPatterns[],int NO_OF_ROWS,int     NO_OF_COLS);
int main()
{
int array[][5] = {  {0,0,0,0,0}, {1,0,1,0,0}, {1,0,1,0,1}, {1,1,1,0,1}, {0,0,0,0,0}};
const int NO_OF_ROWS = sizeof(array)/ sizeof(array[0]);
const int NO_OF_COLS = sizeof(array[0])/ sizeof(array[0][0]);

int sizeOfreferenceToPatterns = floor(( NO_OF_ROWS * NO_OF_COLS ) / 2);
// this is half the size of elements in the 2D arrays because at most you can have patterns half that of elements logically thinking 
int* referenceToPatterns[sizeOfreferenceToPatterns];
int initialization = 0;

do
{
    // just making sure everything is NULL
    referenceToPatterns[initialization++] = NULL;
}while(initialization < sizeOfreferenceToPatterns);

// I am Traversing

for(int i = 0; i < NO_OF_ROWS ; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < NO_OF_COLS ; ++j)
    {
        if(array[i][j] == 1)
        {
            int element[] = { i, j};
            insertIntoPattern(element, referenceToPatterns,NO_OF_ROWS,NO_OF_COLS);
        }
    }
}

initialization = 0;
mergePatterns(referenceToPatterns);
}

int mergePatterns(int* referenceToPatterns[])
{

}
int insertIntoPattern(int* element,int* referenceToPatterns[],int NO_OF_ROWS,int NO_OF_COLS)
{
bool status = false;
bool thisPattern = false;
if(referenceToPatterns[0] == NULL) // this means i have just started to recognize patterns
{
    referenceToPatterns[0] = (int *)calloc(NO_OF_COLS * NO_OF_ROWS,sizeof(int));
    referenceToPatterns[0][0] = element[0];
    referenceToPatterns[0][1] = element[1];
}
else 
{
    int sizeOfreferenceToPatterns = floor((NO_OF_ROWS*NO_OF_COLS)/2);
    // in case every element is `1`
    int i,j;
    for(i =0 ; i < sizeOfreferenceToPatterns ; i++)
    {
        if(referenceToPatterns[i] != NULL)
        {
            for(j=0; referenceToPatterns[i][j] != 0; j=j+2)
            {
                switch(1)
                {       
                    // this is how i see if certain element can fit into existing pattern
                    case 1:
                        if((element[0] - 1) >= 0)
                        {
                            if( referenceToPatterns[i][j] == (element[0] - 1) && referenceToPatterns[i][j+1] == element[1])
                            {
                                thisPattern = true; 
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    case 2:
                        if((element[0] + 1) < NO_OF_ROWS)
                        {
                            if( referenceToPatterns[i][j] == (element[0] + 1) && referenceToPatterns[i][j+1] == element[1])
                            {
                                thisPattern = true; 
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    case 3:
                        if((element[1] - 1) >= 0)
                        {
                            if( referenceToPatterns[i][j] == element[0] && referenceToPatterns[i][j+1] == (element[1] -1))
                            {
                                thisPattern = true; 
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    case 4:
                        if((element[1] + 1) < NO_OF_COLS)
                        {
                            if( referenceToPatterns[i][j] == element[0] && referenceToPatterns[i][j+1] == (element[1] + 1))
                            {
                                thisPattern = true; 
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                //printf("in the inner for loop\n");
                }
            }
            if(thisPattern == true)
            {
                referenceToPatterns[i][j] = element[0];
                referenceToPatterns[i][j+1] = element[1];   
            }
        }
        else break;
    }
    if(thisPattern == false)
    {
        // if the element cannot fit into one, assume that they behave as a root for a new pattern.
        referenceToPatterns[i] = (int *)calloc(NO_OF_COLS * NO_OF_ROWS,sizeof(int));
        referenceToPatterns[i][0] = element[0];
        referenceToPatterns[i][1] = element[1];
    }
}
}
```

**I left the Merge Patterns, which I think you can go ahead with**